# Port 5432 is listening, but still closed

Tags: postgresql, server, command, port, remote-access

I am struggling  for 3 days already trying to set up Postgres on remote machine in order to connect from other device.

What was done already.

**1. pg_hba.conf was modified**

[image: pg_hba.conf]

**2. postrgresql.conf was checked**
[image]

**3. Opened port in firewall for inbound connections**
[image: firewall inbound rule]

However, port is still closed

[image: port closed]

I am checking on command line and can see the following.
[image: command line 1]
[image: command line 2]

As a result - I cannot connect to postgresql server on remote machine.

Remote machine is on windows server.

Comment: Please add the error message.

Comment: The error is usual for the cases, when the port is closed:
"psql: errror: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/100060) is the server running on host "%ip%" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

Comment: Then it is a network problem for sure. Perhaps you forgot a firewall somewhere.

Comment: Could you please clarify what else should be checked or tested on firewall? Port was opened for inbound connection (screenshot was attached).

Comment: I know, and I cannot tell where the problem is. But it is in the network for sure. Could be something as simple as a wrong IP address in your connection attempt.

Comment: As per screenshots (files and command line) everything looks correct?

Comment: The screenshot doesn't show your complete network.

Comment: You can test the visibility of the remote machine with telnet or ssh: `telnet remote.ip.addr 5432`

Comment: Best guess, there is another firewall between your client device and the server machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Adrian Klaver for her comment.
The problem in my case was that physical machine had another firewall setting, which block this port.